# Convert phpMyAdmin exported database to older version. utf8mb4 issues

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, utf8mb4

I want to move my MySQL database to an older version server (5.7 to 5.1).
I get errors because it is created using `utf8mb4` .
If i manually change `utf8mb4` to `utf8` the data become unreadable because of multilinguality.
I have access only to phpMyAdmin in both servers so I can't use `mysqldump`.
Any ideas?

Comment: The main characters you lose in going from utf8mb4 to utf8 are Emoji and _some_ of Chinese.  Please provide more details, including examples; there may be something else going on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems I've figured out a solution.
Use at export `mysql40` compatibility mode, replace `utf8mb4` with `utf8` and change the character set of tables from phpmyadmin to `utf8_unicode_ci`.
Hope this will save some time from a fellow in future.

Comment: This certainly works but previous data? That might be problem (thinking)